# How to login to the website using requests in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to get data from https://fad.ulearny.it/poloformativolangella.

However, I need to login the page first.

I tried to use requests but failed.

Here is my code:

```
import requests

s = requests.session()

payload = {
    'username': 'my_username',
    'password': 'my_password',
    'retURL': '/poloformativolangella',
    'unique_url': 'poloformativolangella',
    'id_app': '',
    'json': 'true'
}
res = s.post("https://fad.ulearny.it/controller/apps/unilearning/login/json/", data=payload)
```

I know i can do it with selenium but this takes more time so i decided to use the requests but I don't understand where is the error

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Your request is working for me.

Comment: Yes but when I want to have the response of the authorized page it gives me the error page

Comment: I don't think I can help you, I don't have credentials to the website itself so I can't debug the app. I'm fairly sure everything you've shown is correct- using sessions to save cookies, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), it has functions for finding elements (like text entry) (e.g. `find_element_by_xpath`) in the HTML page, for sending characters (`send_keys`) so you can type the username and password, and for clicking on buttons (`click`).

Comment: Yes i know i can do it with selenium but this takes more time so i decided to use the requests but I don't understand where is the error
thanks for the reply by the way

Comment: My bad, I didn't read your post carefully enough, you're passing in the username and password. I ran your code, I get a 200 back, so what error are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

You can user library like selenium to do such webautomation.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Drivers\\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://fad.ulearny.it/poloformativolangella.")
time.sleep(2) #giving time for browser to load contents
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div/div[1]/div/label/input")
username.send_keys("your_username")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div/div[2]/div/label/input")
password.send_keys("your_password")
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]")
button.click()
```

Here, you need to install chromedriver.exe and specify the address of that.

You also need to provide `x_path` of the particular element that your trying to send data to.

You can find the `x_path` of the element by going to developer tools in your browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer this works but i only have to do it using the requests library